# Connectivity issues using Doctrine ORM in Symfony 1.4 to connect with Oracle 11g

Tags: php, oracle11g, doctrine, symfony-1.4

System Info:
  PHP Version: 5.3.5
  Database:  Oracle 11g
  Operating System: Windows 7
  Framework: Symfony 1.4
  ORM: Doctrine 1.2

I had an application previously working with MySQL 5.5.8. Now, the client wants the same application to be configured using the Oracle 11g. I figured out the major changes to be in the major changes in schema and model files.

Configuring the databases.yml file as per Oracle, the databases.yml looks as below:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      'oracle:dbname=//localhost/xe'
      username: test_demo
      password: test_demo
      attributes:
        use_native_enum: true
```

When executing the application, it breaks at startup throwing an Internal Server Error saying Doctrine Adapter Exception.

```
Unsupported parameters:$length, $driverOptions
```

at ()
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Adapter\Statement\Oracle.php line 155 ...

```
        public function bindParam($column, &$variable, $type = null, $length = null, $driverOptions = array())
        {   
            if ($driverOptions || $length ) {
                throw new Doctrine_Adapter_Exception('Unsupported parameters:$length, $driverOptions');
            }
            if ($length === null) {
```

at Doctrine_Adapter_Statement_Oracle->bindParam(1, 'ngtn29ghgbvoef356pugl0uao4', 2, 255)
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\storage\sfPDOSessionStorage.class.php line 112 ...

```
          $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

          $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
          $stmt->execute();
          // it is recommended to use fetchAll so that PDO can close the DB cursor
```

at sfPDOSessionStorage->sessionRead('ngtn29ghgbvoef356pugl0uao4')
in n/a line n/a ...

at session_start()
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\storage\sfDatabaseSessionStorage.class.php line 74 ...

```
        // start our session

        session_start();
      }
      /**
```

at sfDatabaseSessionStorage->initialize(array('auto_shutdown' => , 'session_id' => null, 'database' => object('sfDoctrineDatabase'), 'session_name' => 'symfony', 'db_table' => 'app_sessions'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\storage\sfStorage.class.php line 33 ...

```
       */
      public function __construct($options = array())
      { 
        $this->initialize($options);
        if ($this->options['auto_shutdown'])
        {
```

at sfStorage->__construct(array('auto_shutdown' => , 'session_id' => null, 'database' => object('sfDoctrineDatabase'), 'session_name' => 'symfony', 'db_table' => 'app_sessions'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR\cache\frontend\dev\config\config_factories.yml.php line 115 ...

```
    ), sfConfig::get('sf_factory_storage_parameters', array (
      'session_name' => 'symfony',
      'db_table' => 'app_sessions',
    ))));
      $class = sfConfig::get('sf_factory_user', 'myUser');
      $this->factories['user'] = new $class($this->dispatcher, $this->factories['storage'], array_merge(array('auto_shutdown' => false, 'culture' => $this->factories['request']->getParameter('sf_culture')), sfConfig::get('sf_factory_user_parameters', array (
      'timeout' => 900,
```

at require('C:\wamp\www\project\cache\frontend\dev\config\config_factories.yml.php')
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\util\sfContext.class.php line 155 ...

```
        }
        // include the factories configuration
        require($this->configuration->getConfigCache()->checkConfig('config/factories.yml'));
        $this->dispatcher->notify(new sfEvent($this, 'context.load_factories'));
```

at sfContext->loadFactories()
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\util\sfContext.class.php line 77 ...

```
        try
        {
          $this->loadFactories();
        }
        catch (sfException $e)
        {
```

at sfContext->initialize(object('frontendConfiguration'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\util\sfContext.class.php line 60 ...

```
          throw new sfFactoryException(sprintf('Class "%s" is not of the type sfContext.', $class));
        }
        self::$instances[$name]->initialize($configuration);
        return self::$instances[$name];
      }
```

at sfContext::createInstance(object('frontendConfiguration'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR\web\frontend_dev.php line 19 ...

```
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
    $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', true);
    sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

I am new to symfony, also 3 days of google also didn't helped much debugging the issue.
Please Help.

Comment: please format your code..My eyes bleed

Comment: Sorry for that, but this is the symfony framework's doctrine code. I just placed the error stack.